# VB publish profile is not reflecting on project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

[image]

I have modify the existing code and perform publishing with VB but the publishing doesn't seems like reflecting to my new changes and remain on the previous layout. Things I have done

1. reinstall VB
2. reset VB setting
3. install 2019 version instead of the latest.
4. delete publishing profile and reimport publishing profile

It doesn't seems working, need help for this.

Comment: Sometimes, the browser cache might be showing you the previous version of your website. Try accessing your website in a private browsing window or clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

I don't believe it's an issue with Visual Studio itself. I'm not familiar with the specific case of your application, as details are missing, but it occurs to me that it might be related to your browser's cache. Try accessing from a browser that you've never used to access the web application, or from a different computer. You can also try from an incognito window.

I've experienced what you mentioned several times, and generally, this has always been the issue. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what is the root cause, definitely noting related to the browser. However to resolve this issue I just us my backup project and overwrite with the  modified project. It perform the changes as it should.